# What happens to source and destination branches after git merge?

Tags: git

When I run `git checkout branch1` followed by `git merge branch2` to merge two branches it seems like branch2 simply overwrites branch1. Should this be happening?

Edit:

Before merge

- branch1 = readme.txt (Hello World!)
- branch2 = readme.txt (Hello 2!)

After merge

- branch1 =  readme.txt (Hello 2!)

tbh, I'm not sure what a merge is technically supposed to do.

Comment: It depends. Please add more details.

Comment: What it should be doing is to apply all commits you made to branch 2 since the two branches diverged to branch 1. Please be a bit more specific what happens when you do a merge.

Comment: edit: I suppose the merge is in reference to the files merged as opposed to the content of the files being merged.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When merging one branch into another *git merge* will apply all the commits from the branch being merged from to the branch being merged into since the two diverged. You can consider it as forming a new head that contains the latest state from both of the branches put together. If you have changed a file in a branch and you merge it back into it's parent then the changes will be applied on top of the current state of that branch. If both files have changed in the same place then merge may not be able to resolve this and you will have to intervene. Usually though you just end up with the latest work from both branches.

In your example the changes you made in `branch2` have been merged into `branch1`. This appears to be changing the text to `"Hello 2!"`.

The `git-merge` manpage has this to say about it:

> Assume the following history exists and the current branch is "master":
>
> ```
>           A---B---C topic
>          /
>     D---E---F---G master
> ```
>
> Then "git merge topic" will replay the changes made on the topic branch since it diverged from master
>   (i.e., E) until its current commit (C) on top of master, and record the result in a new commit along
>   with the names of the two parent commits and a log message from the user describing the changes.
>
> ```
>           A---B---C topic
>          /         \
>     D---E---F---G---H master
> ```

In short this is the correct operation of *merge*.

Answer (score 4):

If `readme.txt` diverged in `branch1` and `branch2`, merging the branches will result in the file being in the state of *conflict*. The conflict is represented by both variants of diverging contents being present in the file delineated with conflict markers:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD:hello.txt
Hello world!
=======
Hello 2!
>>>>>>> 01234567890abcdef:hello.txt
```

A merge with conflicts will not be automatically committed. Instead, a message will be displayed instructing you to manually resolve the conflict and showing how to commit the changes:

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in <file>
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011046/how-does-git-merge-work/14013007#comment19353533_14013007) by Nevik Rehnel, if the file didn't diverge in the branch, but was simply modified from a common shared contents (`Hello world!`) to a new content (`Hello 2!`), there will be no conflict and the merge operation will simply apply the changes. In other words, a *merge* does not guarantee merging of file contents, but merging of changes compared to a common base.

Comment: Not necessarily. If the branch 2 includes the changes of branch 1 (rather, the changes pertaining to that file), Git can recognize that all changes in branch 2 supersede the other ones (which are common history). In that case, no conflict is created since, apparently, the branch 2 changes were made later.

Comment: I would have thought there should be a conflict but as Bevik Rehnel has alluded there was no conflict. How can I simulate a conflict?

Comment: @Okyekyein You can create a conflict by editing the same part of the file in both branches. So change the text to `"Hello1"` or something in branch one. Then when you merge them git won't know which change to use and will ask you to sort out the conflicts manually. (You can do this nicely with `git mergetool` if it's setup properly on your platform.)

Comment: @NevikRehnel Good point; I've now updated the answer to cover this scenario and removed the claim that the OP is misinterpreting the merge results.